# FrameManager returns NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity

I accessed bottomnavigation view from my container activity and set on item selected listener to the bottom navigation view .
The following code is in my fragment inside onCreateView.

```
b2 = (BottomNavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.botttom_nav);

b2.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.songs:
                    selectedFragment=new SongsFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.albums:
                    selectedFragment=new AlbumFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.artists:
                    selectedFragment=new ArtistFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putStringArrayList("artists",songArtists);
                    selectedFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    break;
                case R.id.playlists:
                    selectedFragment=new PlaylistsFragment();
                    break;
            }
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_main,selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Shows error for fragmentmanager .

Error log is shown below :

```
PID: 22518
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
    at com.noob.audioplayer.SongsFragment$2.onNavigationItemSelected(SongsFragment.java:215)
    at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:204)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
    at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView$1.onClick(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:115)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Is this code in a Fragment ?

Comment: @Maxouille Yes it is

Comment: And is this code inside `onCreate` or `onCreateView` ?

Comment: @Maxouille It is inside the onCreateView

Comment: I think you should try to move it to `onActivityCreated()`. Indeed, `onCreateView()` is called before the Activity is fully created and I think that's why `getActivity()` returns null. The answer proposed to save a context is not the best way to solve the problem imo.

Comment: @Maxouille Can you please explain to me why it's not the best solution ?

Comment: With the `onAttach` solution, you are storing a useless value that will be available in `onActivityCreated`. It's working but it is a storage that is not required. But you should test my proposition as I'm not sure it will work :p

Comment: @Maxouille Well! Tried in onActivityCreated but doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `getActivity()` is null, so you need the context of the activity displaying the fragment.

In your fragment declare a variable

```
private YOUR_Activity myContext;
```

Then in the fragment override `onAttach()`

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
   myContext=(YOUR_Activity) activity;
   super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

Then you call `supportFragmentManager` like this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
```